# Google keeps flipping between custom voice and google default voice

Tags: actions-on-google

We are using Google Action SDK in SSML to respond user in custom voice. But Google keeps flipping between custom voice and google default voice.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code for this to be reproduced?

Comment: I posted an example in below.

Comment: Are you responding directly with JSON or using a library?

Comment: I respond in JSON (ActionSDK) directly

Comment: In the response, when SSML property is present, should textToSpeech property be disabled?

Comment: I would consider including just `textToSpeech` and optionally `displayText` but not SSML, as is shown in [the documentation examples](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/simple-responses#SimpleResponseSSMLSamples).

Answer (score -1):

```
The switching between custom voice and google voice happens randomly. You are not able to consistently reproduce it. Below is an example of the response. The audio source url is the file location stored in Azure storage and it expires in a few mins after generated.

{
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
        }
      ],
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "Hi! I can help you with so many things! Like getting you an auto quote or answering general insurance questions. So what can I do you for?",
                "ssml": "<speak>\r\n  <audio src=\"https://qa01storgapp01dcq.blob.core.windows.net/google-assistant-audio-permanent/LUISIntentsandGetQuoteEntities-9.mp3?sv=2019-07-07&amp;spr=https&amp;se=2020-08-18T19%3A30%3A28Z&amp;sr=b&amp;sp=r&amp;sig=eszRZWEw6sc58xRyz1Y7PrnpP4gyxfDUm%2FGQn9QxElM%3D\">Hi! I can help you with so many things! Like getting you an auto quote or answering general insurance questions. So what can I do you for?</audio>\r\n</speak>",
                "displayText": "Hi! I can help you with so many things! Like getting you an auto quote or answering general insurance questions. So what can I do you for?"
              }
            }
          ],
          "suggestions": [
            {
              "title": "Get Quote"
            },
            {
              "title": "Ask a Question"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "isInSandbox": false
}
```